# How to skip missed data while plotting time series with R?

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I have a text file and want to read data from that for plotting time series as follows.

```
Value   Date    Time
4406    6/13/2016   16:53:23
4422    6/13/2016   17:25:58
4411    6/13/2016   17:31:21
4408    6/13/2016   17:37:00
4404    6/13/2016   17:42:22
-999    6/13/2016   17:47:44
-999    6/13/2016   17:53:12
-999    6/13/2016   18:09:19
-999    6/13/2016   18:20:05
4413    6/13/2016   18:25:30
4418    6/13/2016   18:30:50
4410    6/13/2016   18:36:15
4400    6/13/2016   18:41:46
4397    6/13/2016   18:47:09
4410    6/13/2016   18:58:03
4391    6/13/2016   19:03:29
4449    6/13/2016   19:08:58
4458    6/13/2016   19:14:22
4437    6/13/2016   19:19:49
4406    6/13/2016   19:31:05
4357    6/13/2016   19:36:36
4366    6/13/2016   19:47:53
4363    6/13/2016   19:53:25
4371    6/13/2016   20:04:34
4346    6/13/2016   20:15:50
4347    6/13/2016   20:21:31
4347    6/13/2016   20:27:03
4341    6/13/2016   20:38:13
4330    6/13/2016   20:43:52
4343    6/13/2016   20:55:00
4342    6/13/2016   21:00:31
-999    6/13/2016   21:06:05
4346    6/13/2016   21:11:36
-999    6/13/2016   21:17:14
4347    6/13/2016   21:22:52
4357    6/13/2016   21:28:30
4346    6/13/2016   21:34:05
4350    6/13/2016   21:39:34
4348    6/13/2016   21:45:04
4359    6/13/2016   21:50:38
-999    6/13/2016   21:56:08
4355    6/13/2016   22:01:37
4357    6/13/2016   22:07:12
-999    6/13/2016   22:12:45
4356    6/13/2016   22:18:17
4359    6/13/2016   22:23:50
4358    6/13/2016   22:29:26
4360    6/13/2016   22:34:53
4367    6/13/2016   22:40:20
-999    6/13/2016   22:45:54
4371    6/13/2016   22:51:21
4367    6/13/2016   22:56:49
```

I have a R code for plotting time series as follows.

```
dm <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
dm$Date <- as.Date(dm$Date, "%m/%d/%Y")
plot(Value ~ Date, dm, xaxt = "n", type = "l")
axis(1, dm$Date, format(dm$Date, "%b %d"), cex.axis = .7)
title(main= "Time Series", font.main=4, xlab= "Time", ylab= "Water Level")
```

I want to modify the code to stop plotting when the value is -999 and then continue plotting. Would you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert -999 to `NA` (the missing value code in R).

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

dm$datetime = mdy_hms(paste(dm$Date, dm$Time))
dm$Value[dm$Value == -999] = NA
```

To plot with base graphics:

```
plot(Value ~ datetime, dm, xaxt = "n", type = "l", xlab="", ylab="")
breaks = seq(floor_date(min(dm$datetime), "hour"), max(dm$datetime)+3600,"1 hour")
axis(1, breaks, format(breaks, "%H:%M"), cex.axis = .7)
title(main= "Time Series", font.main=4, xlab= "Time", ylab= "Water Level")
```

[image]

To plot with `ggplot2`:

```
ggplot(dm, aes(datetime, Value)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(size=1) +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks="1 hour", date_labels="%H:%M") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

You can also set the `NA` values when you read in the data, and then you won't have to do the conversion afterwards. For example, if you're reading the data with `read.table` or `read.csv` you can set `na.strings = "-999"` as an argument in either function.